# How to use Humanizer in a Razor page? / 'ByteSizeExtensions.Bytes(byte)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, razor-pages, blazor-server-side, humanizer

When trying to use `Humanizer` in a Blazor Razor Page

```
// _Imports.razor
@using Humanizer;

// Page.razor
@file.Size.Bytes.ToString()
```

I get this error:

```
Error   CS0119  'ByteSizeExtensions.Bytes(byte)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context
```

Using `Humanizer` without a Razor page, directly in standard c# code, works fine.
Why do I get this error? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
It needs to be

```
@file.Size.Bytes().ToString()
```

instead of

```
@file.Size.Bytes.ToString()
```